# Crop rounded image from onPictureTaken result

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview, crop

I have below situation:

[image]

I have full screen `SurfaceView` and in the first half I have my circle where I want to get my final resul from Image Cropping process.

below is the method where I get my bitmap image:

```
 @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //opts.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);

//here I have to crop my image to be fit and have the same place like my circle.
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

- **Programmatically:** can use a method like getRoundedShapeImage which crop image in rounded shape.
- **Using Design:** can use a square shape image having circular from inside and transparent inside circle, then set it as src of your imageView and set picture to background of imageView

I think 2nd one is better, because it will take less time and it is easy as compare to first one.

Comment: Thank you for your response but is not what I want. I want to have a bitmap smaller than my "img" bitmap that have the same size like my drawable circle or closer and take corresponding portion of circle position in the image

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom circleimageview.

I found this library. Github link: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

usage

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/circle_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    app:border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

After you can set bitmap to circle imageview in pictureTaken method.

```
CircleImageView iv=(CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.circle_image);
iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```